# Why does my Navigation Drawer thinks it's closed but remains open after rotation?

Tags: android, rotation, navigation-drawer

I'm currently implementing a Navigation Drawer in my app. Things are working good, but I've run into an issue with the Drawer thinking it's closed after I rotate my device despite it still being visible. Here are a couple of screenshots that illustrate the issue:

**Before rotation:**
[image: Before Rotation]

**After rotation:**
[image: After Rotation]

**History** is the title of the section I was viewing before I opened the Drawer. I preserve the ActionBar title in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onCreate()`, but the function I'm using to set the title is supposed to set the title to the app name when the drawer is open:

```
private void setTitle(String title)
{
    gSectionTitle = title;
    TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);

    if(actionBarTitle != null)
    {
        // Only set a title if we're looking at History or if the Navigation Drawer is open
        Boolean navDrawerOpen = gNavDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(gNavDrawerList);

        // DEBUG
        Log.i(TAG, "navDrawerOpen: " + navDrawerOpen + ", section: " + gSection + ", section title: " + gSectionTitle);

        if(navDrawerOpen)
        {
            actionBarTitle.setText(gNavDrawerTitle);
        }
        else if(gSection == SECTION_HISTORY)
        {
            actionBarTitle.setText(gSectionTitle);
        }
        else
        {
            actionBarTitle.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

(I use a custom ActionBar layout so I can't just use `getActionBar().setTitle()`.)

You'll notice I have a `Log.i()` in that function - here's what it says when the Navigation Drawer has been opened (as in that first picture):

`navDrawerOpen: true, section: 1, section title: gSho`

And here's what it says when it gets called after rotation (as in the second picture):

`navDrawerOpen: false, section: 1, section title: History`

As you can see, the Navigation Drawer remains open but the app thinks that it's been closed, so it restored the currently visible section's title. I followed the Navigation Drawer tutorial and I remembered to setup `onPostCreate()` and `onConfigurationChanged()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    gNavDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    gNavDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

And there's nothing special here, but here's my `ActionBarDrawerToggle` all the same:

```
// Change the ActionBar whenever the drawer is opened or closed
gNavDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, gNavDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
{
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
        // As per navigation drawer guidelines, show the app name and hide elements on the ActionBar
        setTitle(gNavDrawerTitle);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
    {
        setTitle(gSectionTitle);
        // Show hidden Action Bar elements
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};
```

The above code works fine *until* I rotate my device, at which point the wrong title is restored to the ActionBar because it thinks the Navigation Drawer is closed when it's still open. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling it before the `DrawerLayout` has had enough time to layout. You could call `View.post` on your `DrawerLayout` then log it in the `Runnable`.

Comment: Ah, it seems there's more than one way to skin this cat. I ended up keeping track of the open/close status via a boolean and preserving that in `OnSaveInstanceState()`. Should I post that as a solution, or do you think this method is more robust?

Comment: This way is more robust, alternatively you could use a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding calls to `super.onDrawerClosed()` and `super.onDrawerOpened()` like so:

```
// Change the ActionBar whenever the drawer is opened or closed
gNavDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, gNavDrawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.app_name, R.string.app_name)
{
    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
    {
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        // As per navigation drawer guidelines, show the app name and hide elements on the ActionBar
        setTitle(gNavDrawerTitle);
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
    {
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        setTitle(gSectionTitle);
        // Show hidden Action Bar elements
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your activity AndroidManifest.xml. This avoid your activity restarts when you rotate the device. Also when you hide the keyboard and when the screen size changes.

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

Comment: I don't think this is really a good idea in 2015 - shouldn't apps be designed to properly handle the lifecycle instead of ignoring parts of it?